# I made a New website, bought domain from Godaddy, hosting server from github, I'm able to open the site only in my computer?

Tags: html, css, web, bootstrap-modal

My website http://www.whygoogle.com
My github profile faraaz-ali.github.io
I'm able to visit my site only through github bit not directly.

When I try to open my site from other computers it's saying website coming soon

Comment: The site works fine through both domains, DNS changes can take a while to propagate.

Answer (score 0):

I am also able to see your website, If you have changed the nameservers for the domain few hours back. Please note that DNS changes will take 24-48 hours to propogate.

Meanwhile you can use the proxy link to check if the website fetches the latest content

Proxy - [anonymouse.org](http://anonymouse.org/)

Comment: When i tried to view from my colleague's laptop, it doesn't load. When i tried to open from my phone, it says website coming soon.Did you try opening using my domain or github profile?

Comment: Its because your network shares same IP range. You can view your website withing next 24 hours.

Comment: I checked with the above proxy provided by you, it keeps loading but no content is displayed.

Comment: Its better if you could check after few hours clearing your browser cache.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion :)